# C++ Rename File @ C:\Windows\System32\Drivers

Tags: c++, windows, rename

SOLVED: have a look on the later posts

TASK: rename a file called TabletFilter.sys ( its my graphic tablet driver ) because windows 8 (my OS) apps needs an other driver then photoshop for the pin pressure. And I want to write a c++ program that just rename all driver files to .old

The code based on the rename example from cplusplus.com

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int result;
  char oldname[] ="TabletFilter.sys";
  char newname[] ="TabletFilter.sys.old";
  result= rename( oldname , newname );
  if ( result == 0 )
    puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
  else{
    result= rename( newname , oldname );
    if( result == 0)
      puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
    else
      perror( "Error renaming file" );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I tried "run as Admin" as well, but I still get

```
Error renaming file: No such file or directory
```

what can I do?

---

EDIT:

The file is definitly in the same folder ... i copyed them both there... even at c:\windows\ i tryed it ... and i use a manifest

```
Executable: TabletRenameDriver.exe 
Manifest: TabletRenameDriver.exe.manifest
Sample application manifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="TabletRenameDriver"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

i tryed uiAccess true and false.

Yes I have a problem with the rights
The driver is loaded but iam still able to change his name ... dont know why, but its possbile. I tryed it. I want to solve this problem with c++ so pls dont tell me that there are many script languages out there that can handle the problem very well ;-) I know this

Comment: Where are you running this?  The file names aren't fully-qualified with folder names, so I imagine it's looking for the file in the current working directory.  It's probably a lot safer to use the full path name for the file in your code in this case.

Comment: I tryed both versions before I started to ask. I put the exe into the same folder like the TabletFilter.sys .

Comment: You don't need a C++ program to rename a file. A script will do the job.

Comment: I want to change the driver by using a shortcut + plugout/in the device

Comment: I tryed it with  system( "ren TabletFilter.sys  TabletFilter.sys.old"); but this wont work too .... in a non system folder it works... bot not where I need it

Comment: What makes you think it is possible to rename a driver file? Why would the C++ program succeed where `ren` fails? If `ren` fails then you have not got sufficient rights to rename, or the file is locked. Why are you using `system`? If you want to rename a file, call the appropriate library function. You would use `ren` from a command script. Why do you feel you need C++ here?

Comment: What makes you think you even have the right to modify my `Windows` directory?

Comment: There are a large number of ways this is not going to work.  Starting with requiring Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(), the probable reason this attempt failed early.  Next are UAC which stops you from accessing this directory.  Your anti-malware software which stops you from messing with drivers.  The need to get the original driver unloaded with the likely side-effect of crashing the user-mode portion of this code.  And the need to get the new driver started somehow.  Odds for success are very low.

Comment: @ Jonathan Grynspan: I want to modify my Windows directory ... not yours

Comment: thx Hans Passant! that was the needed hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help

I finished my programm  and it works perfectly now

note: added "requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" via VS2012 Settings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void main ()
{
    bool success = false;
    bool somethingWentWrong = false;
    PVOID OldValue = NULL;
    if( Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue) ) 
    {
        success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\TabletFilter.sys", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\TabletFilter.sys.old");
        if(success){
          puts("from .sys to .sys.old");
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys.old");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf.old");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat.old");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
        }else{
          puts("from .sys.old to .sys");
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\TabletFilter.sys.old", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\TabletFilter.sys");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\TabletFilter.sys.old not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys.old", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys.old not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf.old", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf.old not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat.old", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat.old not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
        }
        if(somethingWentWrong){
          puts ( "ERROR: File were set to standart!" );
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\TabletFilter.sys.old", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\TabletFilter.sys");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\TabletFilter.sys.old not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys.old", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.sys.old not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf.old", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.inf.old not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
          success = MoveFile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat.old", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat");
          if(!success){ puts("ERROR: C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\tabletfilter.inf_amd64_e7d03235d8288d3b\\TabletFilter.cat.old not found"); somethingWentWrong = true;}
        }else
          puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
        Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldValue);
    }
    for(unsigned long tick = GetTickCount() / 1000;  tick + 2 > GetTickCount() / 1000;){
    }
}
```

<strike>With only 48 lines of code ... can a script be shorter?</strike>

PS: Revisiting this post after some time, I think there are quite a few ways to approach this issue differently. However, the main point still stands: If you want to do something like this, you have to run with admin permissions ... and maybe use loops, lists/vectors and some proper string manipulation :-P

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
No such file or directory
```

Means that the current directory does not contain files names `"TabletFilter.sys"` or `"TabletFilter.sys.old"`.

What you can do is either:

1. Specify the full path to the file.
2. Ensure that the current directory, when your code executes, is the directory that contains your file.

However, even when you do this, your program may very well fail. You may not have sufficient rights to modify the contents of that folder. And the file you are trying to rename may well be locked if the OS has loaded the driver.

And as @Hans points out, the [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) could very well be confounding matters for you. The best way to avoid that is to us a 64 bit process.

I see no reason for using a C++ program here. Renaming files is a task best suited to a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Many of those drivers are needed by Windows to startup. If you did succeed in renaming them, bad things will happen to your machine when you restart - namely your machine would not boot.

As a general rule, leave all of the stuff in C:\Windows alone, but this advice is ten-fold more important for the C:\Windows\drivers directory. Touch this folder and anything in it at your peril.

Comment: I would leave everything like it is ... when Medion or Genius start to program drivers that work for win8! I post the code only for other guys with same problems ... till now I dont have problem with this code, even with restarts
with this little helper I just have to plugout my graphic tablet start my program - plug in and update driver and will have a pressure sensitive Pencile for OneNote and windowsApps the other way is more easy and then Photoshop will work ... the other option will be to de/re install the driver everytime I want to use the other program